# Массив списков в паскале

Tags: pascal

здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать массив списков в паскале?

Comment: @dasha009, согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что имеется ввиду под списками. Хотя не важно. 
Примеры:
TList - класс-список предок всех списков: TStringList,TObjectList,TStask,TQueue
Можно в нем хранить другие TList.

Можно так:

```
lists:array of TList; //Всем спискам список
```

Можно иначе:

```
list:array of string;  //Массив строк

Lists:array of list; //Массив массивов из строк.
```

Comment: думаю, за такое "решение" препод этой девушки отправит ее на перезачет

Comment: @Человек_Борща а что такое "список в паскале"? (кстати TList мне опять напомнило "Stop the CClass idiotism")

Comment: а может там просто слово выпало ? и в оригинале звучало как "массив связанных списков". А это уже очень похоже на задачу.

Comment: @KoVadim "массив связанных списков" -- этом массив указателей на записи?

Comment: массив указателей на структуры вида

    list = record
       value:integer;
       next:^list;
    end;

(я давно такое на паскале не писал, мог синтаксис напутать).

Но можно и массив таких структур сделать.

Comment: @DreamChild, > думаю, за такое "решение" препод этой девушки отправит ее на перезачет

Девушка поставила задачу я дал ей несколько вариантов решения. Массив списков - простой 2х мерный массив. 
Класс TList - есть ничто иное как обертка на простым array of pointer, добавление в массив, премещение, удаление из массива.

Потому массив списков выглядит так: 
OneList: array of pointer; //1 список чего угодно
ListOnLists: array of OneList; //1 список, который содержит другие списки. 

Это самая простая реализация массива списков чего угодно.

Comment: НАПИШИТЕ кто-нибудь как в комментариях цитировать и код писать. Не надо исправлять, я это и сам могу сделать потом. 

Далее... Массив структур? тоже не надо мудрить с указателем на след. элемент массива, мы не дерево строим а плоский массив без ветвления. 
Array of TMyRecord - достаточно.

Comment: И о каком паскале речь? Древний торбо паскаль? Delphi турбо? Pascal ABC? Delphi 6, Delphi 7?